# String modification in java

Tags: java, string

Hi i am having string like " MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY " . Now i want remove last two words and add hyphen between words finally i want string like " MOTOR-PRIVATE-CAR' . I tried many times using string methods in java but could not find exactly. Can anyone give a solution for that . Give me a code is plus for me.

Thanks in advance

```
public class StringModify {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    String value="MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY";
    System.out.println("Value-------------------->"+value.replaceFirst("\\s*\\w+\\s+\\w+$", ""));
    } catch (Exception e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. To get all the words from the string before "-", you can use String
   `substring` and `indexOf`  methods.
2. To replace empty spaces with hiphen(-), you can use the String `replace` method.

Here is the code:

```
String value="MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY";
value = value.substring(0,value.indexOf("-")); // get the words before "-"
value = value.replace(" ", "-"); // replace space with hiphen
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with the help of `substring()` and `replaceAll()` methods

```
String value="MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY";
value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("-")); //get the string till -
value = value.replaceAll("\\s", "-"); //replace all the space chars with -
System.out.println(value);
```

I have used `String.replaceAll()` instead of `String.replace()` to use the **regex** for **white space**

`\s` stands for white space character and and while adding it as **regex**, we need to escape it with an extra `\` so --> `\\s`

`indexOf("-")` method returns the index of first occurrence of the String passed, which should be the 2nd parameter to `substring` method, which is the `endIndex`

Comment: (nit pick) While correct and obvious (from my point of view), a little explanation would go along way to helping the OP understand there mistake and hopefully alleviate the need for them to post similar questions in the future - Yes, I'm a grumpy old sod ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not as grumpy as some. Not as old as others :P

Comment: @sanbhat The difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` might help, but otherwise it's a good answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StringModify {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
   String value="MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY";
   System.out.println("Value-------------------->"+value.replaceFirst("\\s*\\w+\\s+\\w+$", ""));

   value = value.substring(0,value.indexOf("-")); // get the words before "-"
   value = value.replace(" ", "-"); // replace space with hiphen
   System.out.println(value);
} catch (Exception e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
}


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with `'-'` which gives you the part of the string in which you need to insert `' '`. Split the string again with `' '` and insert `'-'` b/w the words.

```
String value="MOTOR PRIVATE CAR-PACKAGE POLICY";
String[] phrase = value.split("-");
String[] words = phrase[0].split(" ");

String newValue;
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
  newValue += words[i] + "-";
```

Answer (score 0):

String var = "/";
String query = "INSERT INTO Recieptnumbersetup VALUES('"+Prestring+"'  '"+var+"','"+var+"' '"+post string+"')" ;

PS = connection.PrepareStatement(query);

Use this i have used slash over here i was having same problem.